# Multiplicities of Galois representations in the semisimplification of the reduction of a Tate module

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

Let $C$ be a smooth proper curve, of genus $g$ over a number field $K$. Let $v$ be a prime of good reduction for $C$ above $p>2$, and let $T_pJ$ denote the $p$-adic Tate module of $J$, the Jacobian of $C$.

Let $\overline{T_p}$ denote the mod $p$ reduction of an irreducible subrepresentation of $T_pJ$,and denote by $\overline{T_p}^{\text{ss}}$ its semisimplification.

Let $G_K$ denote the absolute Galois group of $K$, then $\overline{T_p}^{\text{ss}}$ decomposes, as a $G_K$-representation, into a direct sum of irreps. Can one of these representations appear with multiplicity greater than one? I vaguely understand that this should never be the case when $C$ has ordinary reduction at $p$, but am interested to know if this can or cannot happen generally.

A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: $T_pJ$ itself could have irreducible summands of multiplicity $>1$.

Comment: Interesting, is there a particular simple example? I am still interested in a similar question for an irreducible direct summand, so will edit accordingly.

Comment: I don't even understand why you think this might be true. What about an elliptic curve $E/\mathbf{Q}$ with good reduction at $2$ and full rational $2$-torsion?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the $p$-adic Tate module of an elliptic curve is odd for all odd $p$, which should imply that this counter example is an artifact of the prime $2$.

Comment: For an example, simply consider a general curve in a product of two elliptic curves.

Comment: Editing your question whenever someone gives you a counter example is poor form (happened twice so far). Do you think there is no genus $2$ curve so that the $3$-torsion of the Jacobian contains $(\mathbf{Z}/3)^2$?

Comment: @user491858 I think I see the point now: the residual representation of my Tate module is given by the Galois action on $p$-torsion, and by taking extensions of the base field I can trivialize it as a Galois module. The example you gave was an artifact of the prime $2$ and my counter argument was an artifact of Tate modules of elliptic curves over fields which have a totally real embedding.

Comment: The example I gave was not an "artifact" of anything. It was just the most simple obvious example. Usually when someone keeps changing the question they have something else in mind they are having trouble formulating and it's tiring to have to guess what that is. One might say "trivialize the $p$-torsion" and then you could come back and demand that $K$ is fixed and $p$ is large.